# TypeScript definitions for WinJS

Tags: typescript, winjs

Where are TypeScript definitions for the [WinJS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn632015)?

**Actually why is WinJS not written in TypeScript in the first place?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions for WinJS are here:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/winjs

WinJS pre-dates TypeScript. That's not to say they won't transfer it to TypeScript now given TypeScript 1.0 was officially announced last night.

Answer (score 1):

There are also some definitions in the Official TypeScript repository found here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#typings/

They might be the same as the one on DefnitelyTyped but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems WinJS definitions on DefinitelyTyped are not updated which is sad.
So best source today is probably WinJS github repo: https://github.com/winjs/winjs/tree/master/typings/winjs

Answer (score 0):

[I have a tutorial](http://www.davevoyles.com/how-to-add-type-definitions-to-a-typescript-project/) about when to use DefinitelyTyped vs Typings, as I found both of them to be very confusing.

TypeScript wasn't a think when WinJS was first created as well. Not everyone wants to use TypeScript, so to get web developers on board, I'd imagine that simply using JavaScript is a better starting point than requiring them to learn a new language (TypeScript) on top of learning the WinJS programming model.